# Python opencv 3 SIFT feature extraction

Tags: python, opencv, feature-extraction, sift, surf

I want to change the following two commands which are written in opencv 2.3 .

```
fea_det=cv2.FeatureDetector_create("SIFT")
des_ext=cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create("SIFT")
```

In opencv 3, I know that there is a command which create SIFT, so

```
fea_det=cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
```

But what should I use for des_ext ? I am asking that what is the equivalent code of "`cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create("SIFT")`" in opencv 3?

Comment: First [_google search_](https://www.google.com/search?q=opencv+3+sift+python&oq=opencv+3+sift+&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i60j69i57j0l3.3034j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). SO is not a _how to search this on search engine_ website!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FeatureDetector_create and DescriptorExtractor_create since OpenCV 3 were moved to xfeatures2d subdirectory.

```
>>> sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
>>> (kps, descs) = sift.detectAndCompute(gray, None)
>>> print("# kps: {}, descriptors: {}".format(len(kps), descs.shape))
# kps: 274, descriptors: (274, 128)
```

Take a look for more information at [this article](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/16/where-did-sift-and-surf-go-in-opencv-3/).

Comment: If answer was useful for you, please mark it as correct